# How to solve this forEach loop problem in wp?

Tags: wordpress, foreach

In one of my WordPress Project, I had to post a get request and render the response data in the front end. To render the data I tried to use the forEach() loop but it always shows undefined but the same thing works fine if I use map().
Now I just want to know what's the problem with forEach(). I am giving both the working and not working code below:

Not working:

```
    getResults() {
    $.getJSON(`http://localhost/from_wp_course/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=${this.searchField.val()}`, posts => {
      this.resultsDiv.html(`
        <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">General Information</h2>
        <ul class="link-list min-list">
          ${posts.forEach(item => `<li><a href="${item.link}">${item.title.rendered}</a></li>`)}
        </ul>
      `);
    });
  }
```

[image]

Working:

```
getResults() {
    $.getJSON(`http://localhost/from_wp_course/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=${this.searchField.val()}`, posts => {
      this.resultsDiv.html(`
        <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">General Information</h2>
        <ul class="link-list min-list">
          ${posts.map(item => `<li><a href="${item.link}">${item.title.rendered}</a></li>`).join('')}
        </ul>
      `);
    });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.foeEach` return value is undefined (why you get the undefined) but `.map` returns a new array.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it more?